# android - How to connect the Device to the Emulator

Tags: android

My Application is working properly in emulator. I am running the application in the device using the ".apk" file. But it is not working properly. So i want to test the application in the device using Eclipse logcat. How to connect the Real device to the Eclipse for debugging the application in the device.  I follow the steps of this link "http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html" . i am facing the problem after setting the path (i.e,The Google USB Driver is located in \google-usb_driver). The error is the hardware is not installed. How to handle this. My device is "Samsung Galaxy Apollo GT-i5801". Please can anybody help me.

thanks

Comment: please send the link of "Samsung Galaxy Apollo GT-i5801" USB Driver Software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samsung has a generic driver for various mobile phones. You need to download and install usb driver from [**this url**](http://www.multi-unlock.com/download/nspro/Drivers/SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones_v1.3.400.0.exe). After installing the driver and connecting the phone to your computer you need to configure eclipse so that it deploys & runs your program on the device.

Comment: How to configure Eclipse for the device connection.

Comment: When you try to debug it should ask you. Like here: http://www.brokenteapotstudios.com/android-game-development-blog/2011/05/16/android-device-chooser.png

Comment: i connected the device.but i am getting this error when the application running "gen_timer_add_locked" repeatedly. what is this error?

Answer (score 0):

In your phone, be sure you have enable the debug mode (Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging). If you enable it, and with eclipse open, when you connect the phone to the computer, it tries to install the device. Usually, there's no problems,but if there's any, just download the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the answer provided by Finuka. After you connect the phone, open the DDMS perspective in Eclipse. Any connected phone or emulator will be listed there. You will also see hooks to running apps on those devices. Select your phone+app to see LogCat.